# mysqli_fetch_assoc in object

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

how to do array in object or with arrow to right. sorry i'm still a junior

this is function and worked

```
 function check_level($id) {

  global $connect;
  $query  = "SELECT level FROM s_user WHERE id='$id'";
  $result = $connect->query($query);
  $level  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ['level'];

  return $level;
  }
```

I was try like this but error, idk how to array in object

```
function check_level($id) {

  global $connect;
  $query  = "SELECT level FROM s_user WHERE id='$id'";
  $result = $connect->query($query);
  $level  = $result->fetch_object(['level']);



  return $level;
  }
```

can you help me ? thanks.

Comment: I would recommend checking the return value of the query before assuming that the result is a result set, so split it into stages and check for errors as you go along.

Comment: error : Trying to get property 'level' of non-object in @Mr.Blue

Comment: idont understand what dou want @NigelRen

Comment: You should read the manual about the correct usage of [`->fetch_object()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php)

Comment: Check if there is a record retrieved before returning a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have solved it already. But here's the function anyway, that checks if there is a result before returning a value.

This function returns NULL if no record retrieved.

```
function check_level($id) {
  global $connect;
  $level = NULL;

  $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT level FROM s_user WHERE id= ?");
  $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->get_result();

  if($result){
      if($result->num_rows > 0){
          $row = $result->fetch_object();
          $level = $row->level; // this
      }
  }
  else {
      echo "MySQL Error: ".$connect->error;
  }
  return $level;
}
```

The function also uses prepared statement to prevent sql injection attacks.

Comment: The function uses prepared statement to prevent sql injection attacks. It also has error checking for result retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

Read more about sql injection. You have to prepare and bind the parameter as code above. The $stmt is only "statement" or variable.